# Upgrade Media Centre Screen Skoda Superb 2018

Tags: electronics, skoda, entertainment-system

I'm generally pretty happy with my Skoda.

However, I recently rented a newer car with a centre-console screen of about the same size but a much higher resolution. This made a surprisingly big difference to the experience of using CarPlay.

So, is it even possible to retrofit a higher resolution screen in this car? Everything on there looks pretty tightly coupled and not very modular.